# Opening multiple application instances from panel shortcuts

Tags: debian, linux-mint, panel, desktop-shortcuts, lmde

In Linux Mint Debian Edition 4, is it possible to open multiple instances of an application by clicking multiple times on its panel shortcut? Currently, I can only open *one* instance and clicking on the panel shortcut minimizes/maximizes the window. With desktop shortcuts, this works without problem.

Comment: First of all some applications do not support multiple instances. Also what do you see when right-clicking the panel shortcut?

Comment: I see this: https://ibb.co/TrRH4Fb

Comment: How can an application "not support" multiple instances? If I (or the OS) decides to open multiple instances, what mechanism can prevent me (or the OS) from doing so? No application should have that kind of control or at least it should be possible to crowbar it

Comment: Each application, that doesn't "support" this, has it's reasons. Try for example doing this with audacity. Now to be clear, there are always workarounds.

Comment: I agree, it's a useful functionality for a developer, but at the end it's the users' decision and responsibility... BTT: Any idea how to solve this issue? It's astronomically annoying. The very reason for having a file explorer shortcut in the panel is for the exact reason of being able to quickly open multiple windows (without having to minimize all windows first or launching it over the terminal)

Comment: Does this happen in all applications, or just a few? For example when right-clicking Firefox does it show the "New Window" option? If so what applications have that problem? Is it just the file manager?

Comment: You're right, **Right Click + New Window** (or similar option) does the trick!